# Volley library didn't work on android 2.3

Tags: android, android-volley

Volley library didn't work on android 2.3.
Hello. I have a problem.

When I send post request, I receive Server Error. Code 400.

```
W/System.err﹕ com.android.volley.ServerError
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run
```

On other android versions all work fine.

Thanks.

Comment: check the status code of the error, so that you can know the exact reason of the error.

Comment: then it is not the problem of volley, requesting is reaching to the sever but server could not understood the client request.
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: on other versions of android - all work well

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of this problem.

String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(str.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
params.put("Authorization", auth);

I replaced Base64.DEFAULT to Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP